# Crawl Website With Wget With Filter by URL Patterns

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to crawl a website and want wget to recursively follow all the links (that are within the same domain) but only download the page if the URL of that page matches a pattern.

I tried something like this:

```
wget https://www.abc.def --no-clobber -r -e robots=off -U mozilla --domains abc.def --html-extension --accept-regex 'https://www.abc.def/g/h/.*'
```

It indeed only downloads pages with 'https://www.abc.def/g/h/.*' pattern.  However, it doesn't try to follow other links at all.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about if you add `--mirror`?

Comment: what does it really do?  I don't quite understand it in manpage: --mirror
           Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l
           inf --no-remove-listing.